# Count SQL entries that contain X and check day

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I've got a calendar (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc2A3.jpg) that I'm developing using PHP. I'm trying to count entries that contain the relevant time (eg. '10' - specific to the hour) from my pickupTime column in my database (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8U02.jpg) and fill the '(X)'s on the table with the number count. Lastly it separates this by day (eg. Monday) by checking the date in pickupTime.

While researching how to do this I found some questions & answers that allow me to query a table and see the number of entries that contain X. However, I can't find anything that is specific to this in the sense that it will simply search the first two digits of the time (eg. 10).

I can edit this to include code but I'm not sure how much it will help, my table consists of rows such as the one below and I'll be running the PHP code within within the cell.

```
            <!-- 10:00 -->
            <tr style="font-size:15px">
                <td>
                    <span>
                        <p style="float:left">10:00</p>
                        <p style="float:right">(x)</p>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
```

I'm not sure if I'm asking for too much here but I thought I'd seek some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HOUR` function will extract the hour from a datetime. And `DAYNAME` will extract the day of the week.

```
SELECT DAYNAME(pickupTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM bookings
WHERE HOUR(pickupTime) = 10
GROUP BY day
```

All the date and time functions can be found in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: That works well, thanks a lot. I'll try implement it in my code.

Comment: Any idea why this isn't working? SELECT DAYNAME(pickupTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM bookings
WHERE HOUR(pickupTime) = 13
AND day(pickupTime) = 'Friday'

Comment: It should be `AND DAYNAME(pickupTime)`

Comment: `DAY(pickupTime)` returns the day of the month, not the day of the week.